# Optimization of 3D graph position calculations

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I am trying to find reasonable algorithm for 3D grpah visualization. So far I've been using Force directed graph with octree for optimization. But the speed of computation is very bad.

My dataset is network traffic record and consists of thousands of nodes that are randomly distributed within it, so nodes that are connecting to one another can be in various places. What's also important is that I am reading line by line and this way I am adding new nodes to program.

Pseudo code for my current algorithm would be:

1. Read line form dataset
2. Generate new/update value of existing node
3. Generate new octree
4. Add all nodes to octree
5. Compute forces
6. Return to 1

Is this algorithm correct? Because I still think that the speed of this is very slow.

Comment: The question *Is this algorithm correct?* only makes sense with respect to a given correctness criterion. What is yours? What is the algorithm supposed to produce exactly? I suspect you'll find that what you have in mind is hard to specify, and, once specified, hard to compute.

Comment: If you want to draw a large graph, you should consider at tool like [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org). The world has enough polygonal wheels already, thank you very much.

Comment: I'm confused about the purpose of the question.  Do you know all of the nodes and all of the connections, or are you trying to calculate some of the connections at runtime (like closest point)?  Is your problem purely an issue of "rending" the known graph?

Comment: @Baronz I have no idea at starting point how many nodes I'll have, yet I want to place them nicely in 3D space.